# How a limited access to AWS Web Console can be provided?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I work as a contractor for a large enterprise company and I was assigned to a new project recently for which we need to request resources on AWS. For our project we will need access to EC2 and RDS.

I am not very familiar with AWS, so my question is: will it be possible to get access to AWS Web Console for our team with limited services (access only to EC2 and RDS in our case)? How much work is needed to provide such access (to set up IAM etc)?

I am a bit concerned that I will not get access to AWS Web Console, because I was asked if I needed a sudo user for a VM. It was frustrating for me to hear such question, because I will need several VMs rather than one.

Comment: May be you can use group permissions of the Active Directory on the domain https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/directory_microsoft_ad.html

Answer (score 1):

By default, IAM Users have **no access** to services. In such a situation, they can access the AWS management console, but there will be many error messages about not having access to information, nor the ability to perform actions.

Once an IAM User is granted the necessary permissions, the console will start working better for them. However, it an be difficult to determine exactly which permissions they require to fully use the console. For example, to use the EC2 console, the user would require `ec2:DescribeInstances`, which allows them to view details about *all* EC2 instances. This might not be desirable in your situation, since they might not want these users to see such a list.

Then comes the ability to perform actions on services, such as launching an EC2 instance. This requires the `ec2:RunInstances` permission, but also other related permissions to gain access to security groups, roles and networking configuration.

**Bottom line:** Yes, you will be able to access the AWS management console. However, your ability to view or do things will be limited by the permissions you are provided.

Comment: Is it possible to use projects to segregate resources in AWS (similar to GCP)? How it might affect setting up IAM permissions?

Comment: AWS does not have anything named "projects". I had a brief look at the GCP documentation and think that it might be similar to [AWS Resource Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/userguide/welcome.html).